Django where to store model-level variables
So I have my model:
from django.db import models

x_default_coordinate = 0
y_default_coordinate = 0

class MyModel(models.Model):
  location1 = gis_models.PointField(
        srid=4326, default=Point(x_default_coordinate, y_default_coordinate)
    )
  location2 = gis_models.PointField(
        srid=4326, default=Point(x_default_coordinate, y_default_coordinate)
    )

Where would be an appropriate place to store the default coordinates? Currently I have them as shown, but that doesn't seem right.

Although there is nothing wrong with your method, keeping them inside the model as class attributes might be slightly preferable. You can also have a separate Python module for all constants.

Would that look like
def hello_world():
  return "Hello world"

Or
class Model(models.Model): 
    hello_world = "Hello world"

Or would either work?
(Sorry, typed this on my phone)

"Currently I have them as shown, but that doesn't seem right." Why not? What do you mean by "right"? Does it work?

I'm not familiar with the Point object and whatever package you are using, so I'm going to answer your question assuming that Point is a mutable object.
The docs
for Field.default:

The default can’t be a mutable object (model instance, list, set, etc.), as a reference to the same instance of that object would be used as the default value in all new model instances. Instead, wrap the desired default in a callable.

To avoid accidentally mutating the default object, you should wrap the default in a callable:
DEFAULT_X = 0
DEFAULT_Y = 0

def get_default_point():
    return Point(DEFAULT_X, DEFAULT_Y)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    location1 = gis_models.PointField(srid=4326, default=get_default_point)
    ....


You can keep them in your class and do something like this:
class YourModel(models.Model):
    X_DEFAULT_COORDINATE = 0
    Y_DEFAULT_COORDINATE = 0

    # your codes.
    ---

I'm guessing the name of your model is not Model as you presented. If so, perhaps you can use a unique and meaningful name so as to avoid confusion with Django's Model
